# How to convert noun Synset datatype into string?

Tags: java

how to convert the word noun synset datatype into string in java ?

```
 nounSynset = (NounSynset)(synsets[j]);
```

since I need to pass the meaning of the query to the search engine which have the method that accepts only string
  I tried to store it in a string variable,but I couldn't able to store.
here comes the error of type mismatch:cannot convert `nounSynset` to string.
the string which I tried was given bellow

```
String s= nounSynset
```

Comment: Call the toString() method of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `toString()` method:

```
String nounSynset = synsets[j].toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

first override the toString method in your NounSynset object and return some meaningful string  from there which will be helpful to your search engine and then just call the toString method wherever you need.

```
(NounSynset(synsets[j])).toString():
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about the [JAWS WordNet library](http://lyle.smu.edu/%7Etspell/jaws/doc/edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/NounSynset.html) here, then the "meaning of the query" most likely corresponds to the `.getDefinition()` method (defined on the `Synset` superclass). Or you may need to build up a search query using the array returned from `.getWordForms()` (the list of synonymous words in the synset).